# Can't set up SendGrid with Google domain because of underscore in CNAME

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, sendgrid

I am able to add the first CNAME without the underscore but when i try adding s1._subdomain, the underscore won't allow google domains to add it. It gives me an error saying the name is invalid. Any tips?

Should I change the domain provider or give up on SendGrid?

Comment: Hi, it would be useful if you could perhaps show the problematic CNAME record. Otherwise, it's pretty difficult for anyone to help you out with your problem.

Comment: The underscore character is not valid for a CNAME. You will need to change the name. The hyphen (dash) character is valid except as the first character.

Comment: @DakshrajSharma Send grid is telling me to add the following to the DNS section: CNAME: s1._domainkey.testdomain.com CANONICOL: s1.domainkey.u18781455.wl206.sendgrid.net. Google gives me error, invalid dns name.

Comment: @JohnHanley How do i change the name? Sendgrid tells me to add the name that they give me... I don't see an option to change it.

Comment: Which form are you adding `s1_domainkey` or `s1._domainkey`? Your question and comment are different.

Comment: @JohnHanley s1._domainkey.testdomain.com sorry

Comment: `s1._domainkey` is valid for a CNAME and Google Cloud DNS supports this. Try again, as I think you must have entered an invalid value. Also, edit your question to state the correct information. Not everyone will read the comments.

Comment: @JohnHanley wait hol up

Comment: @JohnHanley yah still no work

Comment: I am still confused by your question. You cannot use an underscore in a subdomain. What is the exact resource record you are adding? `s1._domainkey` (with that spelling) is valid provided you don't have another resource record for the sub-part. For your question, be very precise. Note: My comments are regarding Google Cloud DNS and not Google Domains. If you are using Google Domains, switch DNS servers to Cloud DNS so that you have all features.

Answer (score 17):

`s1._domainkey` should be the name (and not the value) of your CNAME without the last part of your own domain. For example, `s1._domainkey.yourdomain.com` should just be `s1._domainkey`.

Answer (score 2):

Ran into this nearly 2 years later + posting back incase anyone else finds this - with Cloud DNS, you have to be really careful to add the . at the end. e.g. in sendgrid, it lists:
u28693559.wl060.sendgrid.net, which CloudDNS throws a wobbler at. However, if you add the . at the end it works.

See: https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/dns-overview#public_zone

Comment: You're a genius! It does show the . at the end of address in the example, but one would assume it's just the full stop (period) at the end of the sentence.

Comment: Problem: I noticed Google also add a '.' at the end of the CNAME value as well as the host.

This means if you type `sendgrid.net` in the CNAME value, then google will automatically change it to `sendgrid.net.`

Since you can't change that the CNAME value in sendgrid itself, you will have to use an alternative DNS like Godaddy